# VirtualBox won't run win10: Failed to open a session for the virtual machine w10. Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

Ok so I want to get a virtual machine with Windows so I can download applications only on Windows (Not on OSX (I'm on Big Sur 11.2.3 by the way)), so I downloaded VirtualBox, then downloaded the Windows thing which apparently I have to (as seen in one of the pics) (you can tell I have hardly any experience with vms), then I created a new vm in the VirtualBox app, and left all the default settings except for the type of hard drive (which is also in one of the pictures), then I clicked `Start` and it asked me to add a 'virtual optical disk file', so I clicked on the folder button then clicked `add` in the top left, and it gave me this error code:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine w10.

The VM session was aborted.

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: SessionMachine
Interface: ISession {c0447716-ff5a-4795-b57a-ecd5fffa18a4}
```

as you can also see in one of the pictures below. Also, when I leave the screen for a couple of minutes right before I click on the previously mentioned `add` button, this appears:
[image: loading screen which does nothing]

but I tried just leaving it to load, and nothing happened. I have tried uninstalling using the uninstall tool twice, rebooting my Mac, etc etc, and yes I have allowed everything I need to in the `Security` settings. I'm not installing it on a moderator account, but the Windows 10 virtual optical disk file is in `Documents` which the account I'm on has read and write access to, and obviously the actual VM is in applications.

Thanks so much!
Here's the previously mentioned image of the one changed setting:
[image: changed setting]

And here's the pic of the Win10 64-bit I had to install:
[image: win10]

thanks everyone!

Comment: I get this error when trying to start a MSEdge - WIn10 image that I downloaded and put into VirtualBox some time ago but have not booted for a while.  It used to work, today it does not work on OSX Big Sur 11.6.5.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**VirtualBox Version: 6.1.22 r144080 (Qt5.6.3)**

**Host Operating System: MacOS BigSur**

I came across exactly same issue, where clicking on add to choose image was crashing the dialog. This issue persists in the latest version of Virtual Box for Mac.

I could figure out couple of ways to avoid clicking on Add button to choose image.

**First Option:**

Steps:

1. Click on Settings to open settings window for your VM.
2. Choose Storage
3. Select Empty disc and choose Disk image by clicking small disc icon in the Attributes section. Please follow the image to have visual instructions.

[image]

**Second Option:**

Steps:

1. Click on VM's Normal start
2. Once you get the option to choose image, simply cancel the dialog.

[image]

3. Now click on the small disc icon in the bottom of VM's dialog to choose the image.

[image]

Hope this helps. Feel free to comment if you find this post useful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same message because of permissions at directories where the hard disks were stored in. So, just execute VirtualBox 'As Administrator' and all run well.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error on Ubuntu 22.04 machine while trying to start an existing or a new VM-

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine NuacareRocky.

The VM session was aborted.

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: SessionMachine
Interface: ISession {c0447716-ff5a-4795-b57a-ecd5fffa18a4}

I tried a few things as suggested on youtube, but nothing worked. finally, I just upgraded the extension and it worked.

Comment: How did you upgraded the extension pack?